# How to split a 32-bit integer to two 16-bit half-words

Tags: assembly, arm, bit-fields

How can I divide a 32-bit hexadecimal to two 16-bit hexadecimals and store them so the lower one is inside the first register and higher one is inside the second register.

For example I have a data such as 0xB0B0A0A0 and I want to extract 0xA0A0 to R0 and 0xB0B0 to R1 in my code.

Comment: the same way you would do it with variables in any other language.  and then simply translate that to another language (asm).  what part of the arm documentation do you not understand with respect to the instructions, mov and such?

Comment: when you implement it in C and compile it and examine the output what about those instructions do you not understand?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @old_timer. I have to code it in assembly language with basic commands but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Where do you get the value from?

Comment: Which variant of the ARM architecture are you programming for?

Comment: @Devolus I enter the value inside the code

Comment: @fuz Texas Instruments TM4C129XNCZAD microcontroller

Comment: Is the value `0xb0b0a0a0` in a register, or in memory?

Comment: @RaymondChen In a register

Comment: the first question is are you having an algorithm issue or a coding the algorithm issue?  this is why you solve the algorithm in a language you know then simply port the answer to the new language.  if you dont have the arm architecture docs in front of you, stop work and get them.  second question is which instruction set are you using arm has more than one, get the right doc and use the right instruction set.  third, which tool looks like keil, assembly is specific to the tool not the instruction set.  another question which you answered above is what form do you find the input...

Comment: sounds like it comes in from a register...so that is the easiest for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On sufficiently modern ARM chips, you can use the `uxth` (unsigned extend halfword) instruction for this purpose:

```
@ assuming R2 = 0xb0b0a0a0
uxth r0, r2, ror #0    @ r0 = 0x0000a0a0
uxth r1, r2, ror #16   @ r1 = 0x0000b0b0
```

Refer to the [ARMv7-M ARM Architecture Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0403/latest/) for details.

If programming for ARMv6-M targets or if optimising for code-size on Thumb, the second instruction can be replaced with an `lsrs` to reduce code size:

```
lsrs r1, r2, #16       @ r1 = 0x0000b0b0
```

But note that this causes NZCV to be modified.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped a lot.

Comment: we shouldnt simply do their homework for them, although the limited places where this works may affect the assignment.

Comment: @old_timer If this was homework, I want to see the face of the lecturer when OP comes up with `uxth`.

Comment: Yes, exactly...A compiler comes up with uxth for at least one of them a simple lsr...16 will cover the other, so uxth may be a trigger that they used a compiler...two uxth's a trigger that they didnt...

Comment: @old_timer For thumb code, `uxth` for the first and `lsrs` for the second are actually the optimal choices with respect to instruction length.

Comment: yep, yep, I tried the various flavors and architectures lsrs if thumb yes...

Comment: It's my homework but a small portion of it. Since there's no lecture because my Professor is Covid positive and he is in hospital. Thus our laboratory projects getting harder because we can not learn anything. That's why I had to ask it in here. Sorry if I done something bad :( .

Comment: @coffeecattpk No no, it's fine.  Just be up front with homework questions and don't try to cheat on your exams.

Comment: Okay then. I'll make it clear next time if I'm going to use it on my homework. Thanks again to you all who helped me.